# A derogatory term for "a humiliating statement of surrender"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, politics

What do you call the statement someone, or some organization/entity/group, makes when surrending - and when the surrender and/or the statement and/or the circumstances of making the statement are particularly humiliating?

**Usage example:** That's a bit tricky, since use may differ based on the proposed words or phrases

> I was beside myself with indignation listening to the greek goernment's announcement it will accept the EU bailout condition despite the referedum results. It was an utter _______.

**Edit**: I would like something which sounds derogatory, the way you could, say, refer to a country's flag or to a newspaper as a "rag".

Comment: A *bitter pill [to swallow]*.

Comment: Can you add a sample sentence showing how you would like to use the word? Use ___ or [word] to show where it would go in the sample sentence. That will help people better understand what you're looking for, and keep your question from being closed as off-topic (single-word requests require this kind of sample question).

Comment: @1006a: The thing is, the usage example kind of presupposes I have the right word or phrase.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You give us a sentence that shows how the right word would be used, assuming it exists. Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: @1006a: But I _can't_ give you a single such sentence - it has to be something 4-5 if not more, and they would be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Form several example sentences if you feel you need to in order to get across all the nuances of your desired word. More information is much better than no information! This is a standard requirement for single-word requests, because it makes the site work better. Other people are voting on the answers, and we can't read your mind to know whether the answers are appropriate or not, so we need more info from you beyond "I'll know it when I see it". I see you've accepted an answer. It's not hard to form sentences using the word *capitulation*, so perhaps that could be your starting place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Capitulation:**

1). To stop fighting an enemy or opponent: to admit that the enemy or opponent has won; and

2). To stop trying to fight or resist something: to agree to do or accept something that you have been resisting or opposing. (M-W)

Wikipedia informs us that, "The fall of Singapore [1942] was the worst disaster and largest **capitulation** in British history...[and] switched General Percival's reputation to that of an ineffective 'staff wallah', lacking ruthlessness and aggression...".

Comment: Not bad, not so bad... that sounds a bit derogatory. Not terribly, but it's something. I'll take it.

Comment: Greetings from Tralfamadore!

Comment: @einpoklum The derogatory bit gets worse if you realise that Gen. Percival was forced by his conquerors (Japanese army of 30,000) to lead his army of approx. 80,000 British & Commonwealth soldiers into captivity, walking ahead of his troops holding the Union flag side-by-side with the white flag of surrender.

Comment: @RichardKayser  Planet Earth calling Tralfamadore. Salutations!

Answer (score 1):

How about *confession*, *admission*, or *disclosure*?

M-W:

> [*confession*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confession):
>   the act of telling people something that makes you **embarrassed**,
>   **ashamed**, etc. [emphasis added]
>
> [*admission*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admission): a
>   statement or action by which someone admits a **weakness**, **fault**, etc. [emphasis added]
>
> [*disclosure*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disclosure):
>   the act of making something known : the act of disclosing something

Example:

> The Congressman's *confession* OR *admission* OR *disclosure* of a sexting affair with a teenager was
>   humiliating beyond belief for all involved.

Of these, *confession* best connotes a sense of humiliation, i.e., **embarrassment** or **shame**, although *admission* does this also, i.e., **weakness** or **fault**.

Comment: See my edit. I'm specifically interested in a derogatory term.

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks. I saw that. Will have to go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider ***subjugation*** (synonym **subjection**) and ***submission***.

freedictionary.org:

> ***[subjugation](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=subjugation)*** [Wordnet 3.0] *NOUN*
>
> **1.** forced submission to control by others;  [syn: subjugation, 
>   **subjection**]
>
> **[submission](http://www.freedictionary.org/?Query=submission)** [Wordnet 3.0]
>   *NOUN*
>   **2.** the act of submitting; usually surrendering power to another;  [syn: submission, compliance]

Comment: The first does not describe the act of the surrendering party, and both are not derogatory.

Comment: Those were as derogatory as I could find. I didn't see any words in the other answers more derogatory than these; did you?

Answer (score 0):

The formal document/s marking the surrender of one nation/army to another is known as the "instrument of surrender". It could be argued that all such surrenders are humiliating.

Historians have noted that in 1940 Hitler forced the surrendering French Third Republic to sign the armistice (in effect, a surrender) in the same railway carriage in the same forest in which Germany had surrendered (also nominally via an armistice) at the end of WWI.

> An instrument of surrender is a surrendering document of a military conflict, >as those documents are legal instruments. Some such documents are:
>
> World War II

```
>Japanese Instrument of Surrender
>German Instrument of Surrender
>Armistice between Italy and Allied armed forces
```

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_of_Surrender)

Comment: ... But this sounds so technical and neutral... it's not at all like how you would, say, refer to a flag or a newspaper as a "rag" etc.

Comment: Instruments of surrender are certainly both technical and formal  as well as humiliating. Referring to a newspaper as a rag is merely disparaging.

Comment: @einpoklum - perhaps you should edit your question to specify that sort of thing including your example.  Otherwise how are we supposed to know?

Comment: *railway carriage* One of the two things not destroyed by the Germans at the Compiègne Forest site commemorating the German surrender. The carriage was taken to Berlin. The other item was the statue of Marshal Foch, who had accepted the German surrender. It was left to oversee the devastation.